# Can't show ajax request result in bootsrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to display the result of an ajax call in the body of a bootsrap modal dialog. The modal open successfully but I can't change the content of the body.

Here is my code :

```
      $("#formulaire").submit(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post(
        'scripts/jeuZyga.php', 
        {
           // data : donnees
           civilite : $(".civilite:checked").val(),
           nom : $("#nom").val(),
           prenom : $("#prenom").val(),
           email : $("#email").val(),
           dateNaissance : $("#dateNaissance").val(),
           ville : $("#ville").val(),
           couleurPull : $(".couleurPull:checked").val(),
        },

        function(data){

            if(data == 'Success'){

                  $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('Merci de votre participation ! <br/>Rendez-vous pour le tirage au sort');

            }
            else if (data == 'Forbidden') {

                   $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('<p>Vous avez déjà joué</p>');

            }
            else {

                    $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('Erreur lors du traitement de la requête, veuillez réessayer ultérieurement.');


            }


        },
            $('#myModal').modal('show')                 
        //'text'
     );

});
```

});

and the modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Votre participation au Jeu "Gagnez un Pull Zyga"</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

I've tested your code and I've made it to work by moving the *$('#myModal').modal('show')* line outside (after) the $.post code.

```
$("#formulaire").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.post("scripts/jeuZyga.php",
        {
           // data : donnees
           civilite : $(".civilite:checked").val(),
           nom : $("#nom").val(),
           prenom : $("#prenom").val(),
           email : $("#email").val(),
           dateNaissance : $("#dateNaissance").val(),
           ville : $("#ville").val(),
           couleurPull : $(".couleurPull:checked").val()        // no 'comma' here.
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data + ", status: " + status );
            if(data == 'Success'){
              $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('Merci de votre participation ! <br/>Rendez-vous pour le tirage au sort');
            }
            else if (data == 'Forbidden') {
              $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('<p>Vous avez déjà joué</p>');
            }
            else {
              $('#myModal .modal-body p').html('Erreur lors du traitement de la requête, veuillez réessayer ultérieurement.');
            }
        }
        //,
        //    $('#myModal').modal('show')       // moved outside $.post
        //'text'
    );
  $('#myModal').modal('show');        // moved here, outside the $.post code.
});
```

I have also added status, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `#myModal.modal-body` which is wrong instead use `#myModal .modal-body` (the difference is space between #myModal and .modal-body)

```
$('#myModal .modal-body p').html('Merci de votre participation ! <br/>Rendez-vous pour le tirage au sort');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector here `$('#myModal.modal-body p')` is asking for an element with id `myModal` AND css class `.modal-body`

You want to have this `#myModal .modal-body p`. Notice the space after `#myModal` to build the correct selector hierarchy.

Comment: I agree. Explanation of this solution: when you write it without space it applies to the same element. You could do $('#myModal.fade'). It means the element with id=myModal that also has class=fade. Therefore it would apply to the first div with id=myModal because it also has class=fade. You must put a space in between when you want it to apply to an element (class='modal-body') inside another element (id=myModal). Plus, the element 'p' inside the div class=modal-body needs another additional space. Solution: $('#myModal.modal-body p'), as @ClaudioRedi has clearly stated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, unfortunatly it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Acidy: have you debugged to see if callback method is called?